# ASP serverside validation shows not valid and clientside validation shows valid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

When I click my Button to perform the validation, the validation happens correctly on the server side, but at the same time my client side validation always says the page is valid even when the page is not valid on the server side.

**HTML**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="PURSubAccounts" runat="server" Width="150" EmptyMessage=" ---" Font-Bold="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="PurSubValidation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="!!!" Display="Dynamic" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="PURSubAccounts" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="CreateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="CreateButton_Click" OnClientClick="ValidateME();" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ValidateME() {

        if (Page_IsValid) {
            alert("Valid");
        } else {
            alert("NOT Valid");
        }
}
```

**VB Code**

```
Protected Sub CreateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If Page.IsValid Then
        msgbox("Valid")
    Else
        msgbox("NOT Valid")
    End If

End Sub
```

So when I click the button, The vb messagebox says "NOT Valid" and the clientside Alert says "Valid" whilst my error messages on the requiredfieldvalidators are correctly displayed.

I have tried using the Page_ClientValidate() but that also returns true whilst serverside returns false.

How do I go about getting the validations to agree?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom validor rather than Required field validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateCombo" ErrorMessage="You must select an item with even value" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

For your client side validation :

```
function validateCombo(source, args) 
{
    args.IsValid = false;
    var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
    var text = combo.get_text();
    if (text.length < 1) 
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        var node = combo.findItemByText(text);
        if (node) 
        {
            var value = node.get_value();
            if (value.length > 0 && value % 2 == 0) 
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    } 
  }
```

Please try this for server side validation and let me know if it works for you.

```
string selectedValue = RadComboBox1.SelectedValue;
   if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue.Length > 0)
   {
       try
       {
           int value = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue);
           if (value % 2 == 0)
               args.IsValid = true;
           else
               args.IsValid = false;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           args.IsValid = false;
       }            
   }
   else
       args.IsValid = false;
```

Comment: I added the customvalidator now, but it doesn't fires the clientside function at all, not on my button click(causesvalidation=true) nor on indexchange of the combobox(to just even alert me a message that it is valid). Want I want to achieve is that if page is not valid, just display my custom message box and show the requiredfield errors where I have set them...thought I would be able to do it through Page_IsValid(), but looks like I am going to have to code each one individually?

Comment: did you use ClientValidationFunction="validateCombo"  ??

Comment: Yes I did it exactly as above

Comment: The CustomValidator does not run on the client at all, and doesn't even run on the server on an empty field. The RequiredFieldValidator is required, if the field is required.